# ArcGIS Buffer tool leaves out zero width buffers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer

I have a polygon shapefile with 93 objects in it. They have a column with values for the buffer distance. 90 of these objects have 5 as a value, while the remaining 3 have 0.

When I use the buffer tool, the shapefile created leave out the 3 records containing the 0-values, so only a shapefile with 90 objects are in it.

Why is this? I have managed to do this before with 0-values, is there something I have forgotten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not say what version of ArcGIS for Desktop you are using, or whether any warning/error message was returned, but the help on warning/error [000026 : Buffer distance is zero for versions 10.2, 10.2.1 and 10.2.2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp00000009000026) says:

> **Description**
>
> Running Buffer with a distance of zero is not valid, as the expected
>   output would be an exact duplicate of the input.
>
> **Solution**
>
> ... If you are using a field to set the buffer distance, ensure that
>   all records for that field have a value greater or less than 0.

I cannot recall whether this particular software behaviour has changed over time but I am sure that Buffer has had some changes made during the 10.x versions.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I use ArcGIS 10.3. I don't know why it was possible for me to do this before, maybe I should check the output I got..