# Keeping features with 0 buffer width in output shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, buffer

Using ArcGIS 10.3, I am working with a shapefile with millions of small polygons. I am using python to assign buffer widths to each polygon as an attribute. The buffer widths vary, and some polygons are assigned a buffer width of 0. This presents two issues when I use the buffer tool:

1. Polygons assigned a width of 0 receive Warning 000636, because the buffer tool assigns them a null geometry. The sheer volume of these warning messages results in a crash if using the python interpreter in ArcMap (useful for code demonstrations).
2. The polygons themselves are excluded from the final output.

I still need the excluded polygons in the buffer output. I would also prefer not to return a few thousand warnings. For now, my workaround is to assign a buffer width of 0.001 instead of 0. Can anyone give me a better workaround for this issue?

Note: I have found [ArcGIS Buffer tool leaves out zero width buffers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175741) that addresses this issue, but the answer does not provide the guidance I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it says in the documentation that the other question quotes: the buffer tool does not work that way.

The work-around would be:

1. [Export](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm) the features that you don't want to buffer to a separate feature class.
2. Buffer only the features that have valid buffer distances. You could first run a [Select](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm) and export them to their own feature class. Then, buffer that dataset.
3. [Merge](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm) those two results.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

1. Select by attributes (buffer > 0)
2. Run the buffer tool (will only run on the selection)
3. Switch the selection and append to the buffer output (use 'switch selection' or select by attributes (buffer = 0).

Comment: Jbalk - I really like this answer, I didn't know that you could selectively buffer polygons in a shapefile. This actually opens up some very interesting possibilities. It works well in combination with Tom's answer: if you are averse to creating a new feature layer (which would be required to use your selection method in arcpy), Tom's method works well; if memory isn't a restriction, your method may be more streamlined. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Chris.  I'm glad you got something out of it.  For your info - if you have a selection on your feature class, geoprocessing tools in ArcGIS will only run on the selected features.  If you find my answer useful could you please upvote it?  Thanks.

Comment: I like your answer better than my own.